# Function that takes an array as argument. It should return true if all elements in the array are equal, or false otherwise

Tags: arrays, iteration, reduce

I have tried to understand why the reduce method does not return the same thing as every method in this particular case:

```
//1
function myFunction56(arr){
return arr.every(v=>v===arr[0])
}

//2
function myFunction57(arr){
return arr.reduce((a,b)=>(a===b)? true : false)
}
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to leverage the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) callback case where the second argument is not provided and the first array element is used as the second argument (the cumulative value for the first step).

```js
function myFunction57(arr){
return arr.reduce((a,b)=>(a===b)? true : false)
}

console.log(myFunction57([2]));
console.log(myFunction57([2,2,2,2]));
console.log(myFunction57([2,2,2]));
console.log(myFunction57([true,true,true]));
console.log(myFunction57([false,false,true]));
console.log(myFunction57([null,null,null]));
```

But the problem is that your code returns `true`/ `false` after the first step and once it does that , you are not keeping track of the previous value. Your argument `a` (the value you are using for the accumulated value) becomes a `boolean` instead of the previous array element. Unless you have an array of booleans it will not work (as showcased above in one of the examples)

What you want is:

1. to return the previous value, if the 2 elements from the previous step hold the same value (`true` case)
2. or, some different value which none of your elements will equal (`false` case)

```js
function myFunction57(arr){
return arr.reduce((a,b,cI)=>{
if(cI === arr.length - 1 && a===b) return true; 
return (a===b)? a : {}
})
};

console.log(myFunction57([2]));
console.log(myFunction57([2,2,2,2]));
console.log(myFunction57([2,2,2]));
console.log(myFunction57([true,true,true]));
console.log(myFunction57([null,null,null]));
```

Note: The code still does not work for the edge case when `array.length` is 1. But I hope the basic idea gets across.